# Nested Parallelism : Why only the main thread runs and executes the parallel for loop four times?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

My code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "omp.h"

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);  
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for 
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            printf("i = %d, I am Thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
        }    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I am getting:

```
i = 0, I am Thread 0
i = 1, I am Thread 0
i = 2, I am Thread 0
i = 0, I am Thread 0
i = 1, I am Thread 0
i = 0, I am Thread 0
i = 1, I am Thread 0
i = 2, I am Thread 0
i = 2, I am Thread 0
i = 3, I am Thread 0
i = 0, I am Thread 0
i = 1, I am Thread 0
i = 3, I am Thread 0
i = 4, I am Thread 0
i = 5, I am Thread 0
i = 2, I am Thread 0
i = 3, I am Thread 0
i = 4, I am Thread 0
i = 5, I am Thread 0
i = 3, I am Thread 0
i = 4, I am Thread 0
i = 5, I am Thread 0
i = 4, I am Thread 0
i = 5, I am Thread 0
```

Adding "parallel" is the cause of the problem, but I don't know how to explain it.

**My Question is:** Why is there only the main thread and runs the for loop four times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, `nested parallelism` is **disabled**. Nonetheless, you can explicitly **enable** `nested parallelism`, by either:

```
   omp_set_nested(1);
```

or by setting the [OMP_NESTED](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse57.html) environment variable to true.

also from the [OpenMP standard](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) we know that:

> **When a thread encounters a parallel construct, a team of threads is
> created to execute the parallel region.**
> The thread that encountered the parallel construct becomes
> the master thread of the new team, with a thread number of zero for
> the duration of the new parallel region. All threads in the new team,
> including the master thread, execute the region. Once the team is
> created, the number of threads in the team remains constant for the
> duration of that parallel region.

From [source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.10/819-0501/2_nested.html) you can read the following.

> OpenMP parallel regions can be nested inside each other. **If nested
> parallelism is disabled, then the new team created by a thread
> encountering a parallel construct inside a parallel region consists
> only of the encountering thread.** If nested parallelism is enabled,
> then the new team may consist of more than one thread.

This explains the reason why when you add the second `parallel region` there is only one thread *per* team executing the enclosing code (*i.e.,* the *for* loop).  In other words, from the first `parallel region`, `4` threads are created, each of those threads when encountering the second `parallel region`  will create a new team and become the master of that team (i.e., will have the `ID=0` within the newly created team). **However, because you did not explicitly enable the nested parallelism, each of those teams is only composed of a single thread**. Hence, `4` teams with a thread each will execute the *for* loop. Consequently, you will have the following statement:

```
printf("i = %d, I am Thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
```

being printed `6 x 4 = 24 times` (*i.e.,* the total number of loop iterations multiple by the total number of threads across the `4` teams). The image below provides a visualization of that flow:

[image]

If you add a `printf` statement between the first and the second `parallel region`, as follows:

```
int main() {

    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       printf("Before nested parallel region:  I am Thread{%d}\n", omp_get_thread_num());
       #pragma omp parallel for // Adding "parallel" is the cause of the problem, but I don't know how to explain it.
       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       {
           printf("i = %d, I am Thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You would get something similar to the following output (bear in mind that the order in which the first `4` lines are outputted is nondeterministic).

```
Before nested parallel region:  I am Thread{1}
Before nested parallel region:  I am Thread{0}
Before nested parallel region:  I am Thread{2}
Before nested parallel region:  I am Thread{3}
i = 0, I am Thread 0
i = 0, I am Thread 0
i = 0, I am Thread 0
(...)
i = 5, I am Thread 0
```

Meaning that within the first `parallel region` (but still outside of the second parallel region) there is a single team of 4 threads -- with `IDs` varying from `0` to `3` -- executing in parallel. Hence, each of those threads will execute the `printf` statement:

```
printf("I am Thread outside the nested region {%d}\n", omp_get_thread_num());
```

and display a different value for the `omp_get_thread_num()` method call.

As previously mentioned, the nested parallelism is disabled. Thus, when each of those threads encounters the second `parallel region`, each will create a new team and becomes the master (*i.e.,* will have the `ID=0` within the newly created team). -- and the only member -- of that team. Hence, why the statement

```
 printf("i = %d, I am Thread %d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
```

inside the loop, outputs always `(..) I am Thread 0`, since the method `omp_get_thread_num()` in this context will return always `0`. However, even though the method `omp_get_thread_num()` is returning `0`, it does not imply that the code is being executed sequently (by the thread with `ID=0`), but rather that each *master* of each of the `4` teams is returning their `ID=0`.

If you enabled the nested parallelism you will have a flow like shown in the image below:

[image]

The execution of threads `1` to `3` was omitted for simplicity sake, nonetheless it would have been the same as thread 0.

So, from the first `parallel region`, a team with `4` threads is created. After encountering the next `parallel region` each thread from the previous team, will create a new team of `4` threads each, so at the moment we have a total of `16` threads across `4` teams. Finally, each team will execute the entire *for* loop. However, because you have a `#pragma omp parallel for` constructor, the iterations of the *for* loop will be divided among the threads within each team.

Bear in mind that in the image above, I am assuming a certain `static` loop distribution of iterations among loops, I am not implying that the loop iterations will always be divided like this across all the implementations of the OpenMP standard.