# OpenMP - does call paralleled function in a parallel loop still improve performance?

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

If a paralleled function is called by a parallel for loop, does the performance still improve?

Here is a simple example:

```cpp
int main(void) {
    ...
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        res[i] = parallel_function();
    }
    ...
}

int parallel_function() {
    ...
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}
```

In this simple case, I found that the performance of paralleling for-loop in main wasn't improved. But in another complicated case, the performance is improved.
So I'm not sure if paralleling outer for-loop which calls a paralleled function can improve the performance.
If the performance is indeed improved, why? I thought that all available threads have been assigned to for-loop in main, then each thread have to execute `parallel_function` serially. Is it correct?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: First do you have nested parallelism enabled ? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65119234/nested-parallelism-why-only-the-main-thread-runs-and-executes-the-parallel-for for a better understanding

Comment: @dreamcrash No I don't. So I guess that the `parallel_function` will not be parallel executed, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it would be executed sequentially

Comment: @dreamcrash okay I understand. Thanks for providing such useful link.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome, glad it help

Comment: Well, generally it is worth to parallelize the outer loop and not the inner one, but the performance depends on a lot of things (workload, load balance, cache utilization, etc.), so try different setups (and settings). You can also think about combinations (e.g. in a NUMA system 8 threads for outer loop, 2 closer threads for inner loop).  So, without more details we can only give you such general advice. If you would like to improve the performance of your program use a profiler tool....

Comment: Nesting parallel loops is generally a pretty bad idea due to thread over-subscribtion (pointed out by @dreamcrash). You can use the `taskloop` directive (or other `task`-based directives) to eventually solve this problem as well as possible worker starvation possibly due to the small number of iteration (typically on many core systems). Note that tasks still include a small overhead. One should prefer collapsed paralleled for when it is possible due to the smaller overhead. When the number of iteration is big enough in the first loop, it is often better not to parallelize the inner loop.